# ListView is not populating on selecting the spinner item

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have made two spinners - one for selecting city and the other for selecting the area within the city.I am fetching the data for city, area and the `ListView` to display after selecting from the Firebase Database.

I am populating the `ListView` with the help of a custom `ArrayAdapter` which will store the data in a `ArrayList` which will store data in the form of objects of class "vendorsInformation".

My java class which is manipulating data from Firebase database is :

```
public class Location_Selection extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> listVendorEmail=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listVendorName=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listVendorPhoneNo=new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<vendorsInfomation> list_All_info_vendor=new ArrayList<>();

    String categorySelected;

    String citySelected;
    String areaSelected;

    public  Location_Selection(String categorySelected)
    {
        this.categorySelected= categorySelected;

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_selection_page,container,false);

        final Spinner areaSelector=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.select_area);
        final Spinner selectCity=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.selectCity);


        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayAllAstrologers);
        final displayingListAfterAreas listOfVendorsAdapter=new displayingListAfterAreas(getContext(),0,list_All_info_vendor);
        listView.setAdapter(listOfVendorsAdapter);


        selectCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                citySelected = selectCity.getSelectedItem().toString();


                final ArrayList<String> listAreas = new ArrayList<String>();


                String selectedCity = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(selectedCity);

                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String areaId = child.getKey().toString();
                                String areaName = child.getValue().toString();
                                listAreas.add(areaName);
                            }
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(view.getContext(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listAreas);

                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        areaSelector.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        areaSelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                areaSelected=areaSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();

                listVendorEmail.clear();
                listVendorPhoneNo.clear();
                listVendorName.clear();

                FirebaseDatabase database1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference referenceForEmail = database1.getReference(categorySelected + "-" + citySelected + "-" + areaSelected + "/email");

                referenceForEmail.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                String getEmailNo = child.getKey().toString();
                                String getEmailId = child.getValue().toString();
                                listVendorEmail.add(getEmailId);
                            }
                        }


                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }

                });

                DatabaseReference referenceForName=database1.getReference(categorySelected + "-" + citySelected + "-" + areaSelected + "/name");

                referenceForName.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String getNameId = child.getKey().toString();
                                String getName = child.getValue().toString();
                                listVendorName.add(getName);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


                DatabaseReference referenceForPhoneNo=database1.getReference(categorySelected+"-"+citySelected+"-"+areaSelected+"/phoneNo");

                referenceForPhoneNo.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
                        {
                            for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                String getPhoneNoId=child.getKey().toString();
                                String getPhoneNo=child.getValue().toString();
                                listVendorPhoneNo.add(getPhoneNo);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                for(int i=0;i<listVendorPhoneNo.size();i++)
                {
                    vendorsInfomation newObjectToStore=new vendorsInfomation(listVendorName.get(i),listVendorEmail.get(i),listVendorPhoneNo.get(i));
                    list_All_info_vendor.add(newObjectToStore);
                }
                listOfVendorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        return  view;
    }
       }
```

My custom Adapter class is as follows:

```
public class displayingListAfterAreas extends ArrayAdapter<vendorsInfomation> {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<vendorsInfomation> listDisplayingVendors;

    public displayingListAfterAreas(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<vendorsInfomation> objects) {

        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context=context;
        listDisplayingVendors=objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.format_of_list_of_categories, null);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        ImageView image_of_customer=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_of_customer);
        TextView name_of_customer=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name_of_customer);
        TextView email_of_customer=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.email_id_of_customer);
        TextView phone_of_customer=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.phone_no_of_customer);

        image_of_customer.setImageResource(R.drawable.customer_photo);
        name_of_customer.setText(listDisplayingVendors.get(position).getVendorName());
        email_of_customer.setText(listDisplayingVendors.get(position).getVendorEmailId());
        phone_of_customer.setText(listDisplayingVendors.get(position).getVendorPhoneNo());

        return v;


    }
}
```

My vendorsInformation.java class of which form the objects are stored in ArrayList are:

```
public class vendorsInfomation {

    String vendorName;
    String vendorEmailId;
    String vendorPhoneNo;

    public vendorsInfomation(String vendorName,String vendorEmailId,String vendorPhoneNo)
    {
        this.vendorName=vendorName;
        this.vendorEmailId=vendorEmailId;
        this.vendorPhoneNo=vendorPhoneNo;

    }

    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }

    public String getVendorEmailId() {
        return vendorEmailId;
    }

    public String getVendorPhoneNo() {
        return vendorPhoneNo;
    }

    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }

    public void setVendorEmailId(String vendorEmailId) {
        this.vendorEmailId = vendorEmailId;
    }

    public void setVendorPhoneNo(String vendorPhoneNo) {
        this.vendorPhoneNo = vendorPhoneNo;
    }

}
```

I am not getting the `ListView` populated in the view and while debugging the flow is not going inside this for-loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<listVendorPhoneNo.size();i++)
                {
                    vendorsInfomation newObjectToStore=new vendorsInfomation(listVendorName.get(i),listVendorEmail.get(i),listVendorPhoneNo.get(i));
                    list_All_info_vendor.add(newObjectToStore);


                }
```

So there are not items in the `list_All_info_vendor` `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Firebase` uses asynchronous task. Your `List` is probably empty when you are executing the `for` loop therefore it is not entering the `For` loop. You need to move that loop inside the `onDataChange` method.

```
DatabaseReference referenceForPhoneNo=database1.getReference(categorySelected+"-"+citySelected+"-"+areaSelected+"/phoneNo");

            referenceForPhoneNo.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
                    {
                        for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            String getPhoneNoId=child.getKey().toString();
                            String getPhoneNo=child.getValue().toString();
                            listVendorPhoneNo.add(getPhoneNo);
                        }
                    }

 // Move this inside onDataChange.
                 for(int i=0;i<listVendorPhoneNo.size();i++)
            {
                vendorsInfomation newObjectToStore=new vendorsInfomation(listVendorName.get(i),listVendorEmail.get(i),listVendorPhoneNo.get(i));
                list_All_info_vendor.add(newObjectToStore);
            }
            listOfVendorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your lists are empty until the Firebase methods complete.

If you need an adapter in response to that data, then you need to set the adapter where the data does exist.

For example

```
for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String getPhoneNoId=child.getKey().toString();
    String getPhoneNo=child.getValue().toString();
    listVendorPhoneNo.add(getPhoneNo);
}
for(int i=0;i<listVendorPhoneNo.size();i++) {
    vendorsInfomation newObjectToStore=new vendorsInfomation(listVendorName.get(i),listVendorEmail.get(i),listVendorPhoneNo.get(i));
    list_All_info_vendor.add(newObjectToStore);
}
listOfVendorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But, ideally, you should restructure your database so that each piece of information can be gotten from a single database reference because you are probably not guaranteed ordering that `listVendorName.get(i)` and `listVendorEmail.get(i)` correspond to the same data, or that the length of those lists are the same, so you could end up with an index out of bounds exception since you are only looping over the length of the phone numbers